# How to get Ingress to work with game servers with required ports with nodeports on azure

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

My question is specific on the configuration of how to have an ingress controller, in my case the Nginx Ingress controller, work to have users be able to access game servers depending on the port they enter. I assume that they would plug in the ingress server External-IP and then the port that I have on the nodeport correct?

Service 1

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: game-svc-0
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    instance: game-0
  ports:    
    - port: 25565
      targetPort: 25565
      nodePort: 30000 # (default: 30000-32767)
```

Service 2

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: game-svc-1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    instance: game-1
  ports:    
    - port: 25565
      targetPort: 25565
      nodePort: 30001 # (default: 30000-32767)
```

Ingress

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: game-server-ingress
  namespace: ingress-basic
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: game-svc-0
          servicePort: 30000
      - backend:
          serviceName: game-svc-1
          servicePort: 30001
```

Where the stateful set's container port is 25565 as required by the game's docker container.

However when I create the server and run the command

```sh
kubectl describe ing game-server-ingress -n ingress-basic
```

My output says it cannot find certain endpoints. Is this because the ingress is in another namespace? I wouldn't assume this is the issue since this is almost verbatim of the example from microsoft's docs.

```
Name:             game-server-ingress
Namespace:        ingress-basic
Address:          {address1},{address2}
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
                 game-svc-0:30000 (<error: endpoints "game-svc-0" not found>)
                 game-svc-1:30001 (<error: endpoints "game-svc-1" not found>)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Have I configured a part of the node ports incorrectly? The problem is the server input doesn't take in '/words' just an IP address and port as IPADDRESS:PORT. Is this something ingress can even do?

Comment: Are you sure your game uses an HTTP protocol? Most don't.

Comment: @coderanger 
Is there another option on ingress to change that? I have only ever seen http examples

Comment: You wouldn't generally use an Ingress there, you would use a normal Service with the type set to LoadBalancer. Some Ingress Controllers (nginx, traefik) do support non-HTTP usage but not via a plain Ingress, you need to do fancy custom stuff.

Comment: @coderanger I would need to not use LoadBalancer since the cost is much higher than just an ingress controller in azure. With possibly a 1000 or more servers with each on a LoadBalancer is too much. Do you know of any example projects with the nginx tcp udp setup?